# Parsing nested dictionary to dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to create data frame from a JSON file.
[image]

and each `album_details` have a nested dict like this

```
    {'api_path': '/albums/491200',
 'artist': {'api_path': '/artists/1421',
  'header_image_url': 'https://images.genius.com/f3a1149475f2406582e3531041680a3c.1000x800x1.jpg',
  'id': 1421,
  'image_url': 'https://images.genius.com/25d8a9c93ab97e9e6d5d1d9d36e64a53.1000x1000x1.jpg',
  'iq': 46112,
  'is_meme_verified': True,
  'is_verified': True,
  'name': 'Kendrick Lamar',
  'url': 'https://genius.com/artists/Kendrick-lamar'},
 'cover_art_url': 'https://images.genius.com/1efc5de2af228d2e49d91bd0dac4dc49.1000x1000x1.jpg',
 'full_title': 'good kid, m.A.A.d city (Deluxe Version) by Kendrick Lamar',
 'id': 491200,
 'name': 'good kid, m.A.A.d city (Deluxe Version)',
 'url': 'https://genius.com/albums/Kendrick-lamar/Good-kid-m-a-a-d-city-deluxe-version'}
```

I want to create another column in the data frame with just album name which is one the above `dict`

```
'name': 'good kid, m.A.A.d city (Deluxe Version)',
```

I have been looking how to do this from very long time , can some one please help me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that is the case use `str` to call the `dict` key

```
df['name'] = df['album_details'].str['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the dataframe stored in the `df` variable you could do:

```py
df['artist_name'] = [x['artist']['name'] for x in df['album_details'].values]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply with lambda function:

```
df['album_name'] = df['album_details'].apply(lambda d: d['name'])
```

Basically you execute the lambda function for each value of the column 'album_details'. Note that the argument 'd' in the function is the album dictionary. Apply returns a series of the function return values and this you can set to a new column.

See: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html